Where to upgrade Spring or SpringBoot version of the generated stub servers from an OpenAPI 3.0 file with Swagger Codegen
I am an absolute beginner to web development.
I used online Swagger Editor https://editor.swagger.io/ to generate a Spring server stub with the example file located https://github.com/designapis/openapi/blob/main/ch13/01.yml
The generated stub project reference a quite old version of Spring. Extract from the generated pom.xml:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


However the Swagger Codegen version used for generation is the last stable release v3.0.54.
Is there a way to generate server stub for a newer Spring version ?
Should I use another tool like https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator ?
